# How I can do to connect my database in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm new to enterprise architect and would like to know how I can do to connect my database in EA. I need to see the relationship diagrams to do documentation.

I've tried to see the manual provided by sparxs, but I still couldn't.

can anybody help me?

I stopped at step 3 - Select 'PostgreSQL UNICODE' from the list. (https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.0/model_repository/setupapostgresqlodbcdriver.html)

The mentioned option does not appear in the list.

My version is 15

Comment: What do you want to do? Store your EA model in your PostgreSQL database, or reverse engineer your database into EA?. The manual page you mentioned describes the first, for EA v15.

Comment: Hi, I want to reverse engineer my database to the EA.

Comment: You can edit your question to make that more clear.

Comment: I found out that for now I won't need to do the configuration. Thank you for your help.